# Grab info between tags

Tags: php, mysql, html, perl, text-files

I have a text file that has data wrapped between tags. The tags are:

```
<title>
<url>
<pubDate>
```

So, the entries look like this:

```
<title>title 1</title>
<url>url 1</url> 
<pubDate>pubDate 1</pubDate>

<title>title 2</title>
<url>url 2</url> 
<pubDate>pubDate 2</pubDate>

<title>title 3</title>
<url>url 3</url> 
<pubDate>pubDate 3</pubDate>
```

I need a script that reads this text file and prepares each item to be inserted into a database. The query will look like this:

```
insert into table (title,url,pubdate) values ($title,$url,$pubdate)....
```

Comment: So walk through it with an XML or HTML parser, and pluck out the content.  What am I missing here?

Comment: When you look at your data in a text editor or something, is the string "&lt;" present, or an actual "<" sign? This will make a world of difference in the way you parse your data.

Comment: @dsm - are you sure that his data doesn't _actually_ look the way he typed it?

Comment: @Telemachus - It looks too much like a mistake... maybe the author can clarify (@Sunny Rockzzs - opinion?)

Comment: actually the data as seen on notepad corresponds to &lt; but as seen on an XML Editor, like Notepad++ corresponds to the above edited version by dsm

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using '`&lt;`' and not just '`<`'?

Just convert all of the '`&lt;`' and '`&gt;`' to '`<`' and '`>`' then throw it through something like [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm) in Perl.

Comment: It might be a little more complicated: what if the data ought to be "<title>C &gt; Java</title>" But is showing up in his data as "&lt title &gt C &gt; Java &lt /title &gt" ? It would incorrectly replace the '&gt' in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Or SimpleXML in PHP5 http://php.net/simplexml

@rascher there shouldn't be any problem with converting the XML entities to "XML literals".

```
&lt; title &gt; C &gt; Java &lt; /title &gt;
```

Would be encoded as:

```
&lt; title &amp;gt; C &gt; Java &lt; /title &gt;
```

And decoding the XML entities would produce valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen = (); 

sub seen_all {     
      defined $seen{title}
   && defined $seen{url} 
   && defined $seen{pubDate};
}  

while (<>) {                   
     /<(.+?)>(.+)<\/\1>/ && do {
         $seen{$1} = $2;
     }; 

    if(seen_all){ 
        print "insert into table (title,url,pubdate) " .        
              "values ('$seen{title}','$seen{url}','$seen{pubDate}')\n";
        %seen = (); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look at [Text::Balanced](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Balanced). It has a function "extract_tagged" that solves exactly the problem you have outlined.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this. You can read RSS with the Simple XML class

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/path-to-feed.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

foreach($xml->feed as $feed){
    echo $feed->title;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $feed->url;
    echo '<br />';
    echo $feed->pubDate;
    echo '<br />';
}
```